# How do I integrate openCV in reactjs project?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, opencv, image-processing, react-hooks

I'm working on a reactjs project for a few months now one module requires some image processing. So, I would like to know how can I integrate openCV with reactjs. I can't find any articles, documentations for the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried to implement TensorFlow models instead of openCV to your ReactJS project?

Try checking out TensorFlow.js(website:https://www.tensorflow.org/js) They have JavaScript compatible CV models. Maybe that's easier to implement than openCV.

I have completed several projects with TensorFlow.js and ReactJS. They work fine together.

Comment: Thanks, I'll check it out. This library seems a better option for me.

Comment: One more thing please! Can I use TensorFlow to measure the height and width of a face from an image?

Comment: I think you can. Check out this repo: https://github.com/tensorflow/tfjs-models/tree/master/facemesh. This facemesh model is able to detect ~468 landmarks on a face, not including hair though (video level possible), and you can check the locations of those landmarks and choose four of them to calculate the height and width. Hope that helps :)

Comment: Thank you soooo much. I'll check out this repo :-)

Comment: Good luck and wish you the best on your project~

Answer (score 1):

You can use opencv.js for this. Unfortunately there isn't any NPM packages. However you can import it the same way as you would with an NPM package. Just in this case you need to manually download and add opencv.js to your project.

However, opencv.js is huge so I would recommend using a CDN for it.

Here is a link for the NodeJS tutorials of the documentation: https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/dc/de6/tutorial_js_nodejs.html

Further more I would not recommend it on a frontend application. Because of the size and computational power it needs. You could set up a backend API for it with NodeJS

Comment: Thanks for guiding me. I'll surely look into once I check If TensorFlow can work for me :-)